# Is there a common plural of "Freunde" und "mein Freund"?

Tags: grammatical-number

For simplicity all nouns are taken masculine, but also the feminine-case is more interesting (just that I would have to write more cases).

The nouns *(ein) Freund* and *(possesiv) Freund* are different. How to encompass them in plural?

> Sara hat Urlaub mit Freunden und ihrem Freund gemacht.

oder

> Sara hat Urlaub mit ihren Freunden gemacht (stillschweigend: unter denen, ihr Freund).

Is it a matter of emphasis? Or, if the second is chosen, one would derive that all class of *Freunde* that that word describes do not encompass *der Freund*.

Comment: The ambiguity of ‘Freund’ (between ‘friend’ and ‘boyfriend’) has **nothing** to do with whether we use the definite or indefinite article (‘ein’ or ‘der’). Nor does it have anything to do with singular and plural. Suppose Sara and Sue are discussing their past lovers. Sara says: ‘Ich hatte mal einen Freund, der mich betrogen hat.’ Sue replies: ‘Mich haben alle meine Freunde betrogen.’ Given the context, it would be crystal-clear that they are talking about (ex-)boyfriends, and not just friends. That’s although Sara uses the indefinite article ‘ein(en)’, and Sue uses the plural ‘Freunde’.

Comment: Perhaps – but it really depends on the context. Suppose we’re in a restaurant and you’ve asked me to order for you. I might say: ‘Mein Freund hätte gern ein Bier.’ The waiter won’t necessarily conclude that you’re my boyfriend – esp. since it’s said by one man about another. So, while the definite article / possessive have the *tendency* to disambiguate ‘Freund’ as meaning *boyfriend*, they don’t *force* that reading (and plural and indefinite article don’t force the other reading). I think that way my original point: I should have made that clearer.

Answer (score 4):

> Sara hat Urlaub mit ihren Freunden gemacht.

Has Sara a boyfriend? And if so, is he included?

These questions are not answered here.

> Sara hat Urlaub mit Freunden und ihrem Freund gemacht.

This is a clear statement, but bad style. Better:

> Sara hat Urlaub mit Freunden und ihrem Partner gemacht.

We have no commonly used noun to encompass friends and boyfriend.

Comment: And even better: Sara und Ihr Freund haben Urlaub mit Freunden gemacht.

Comment: @Pollitzer, I like your answer in general, but your last example adds a new ambiguity "Partner". As it could also stand for business partner etc. It might not be common, but maybe you have a more distinct solution. "Lebenspartner" would fix it, but sounds wrong.

Comment: @Daniel: Ich habe bei diesem Beispiel die Wortstellung des ursprünglichen Satzes beibehalten, die aber nicht optimal ist. Den Lebenspartner sollte man vorziehen, z. B.: _»Sara hat Urlaub mit ihrem Schatzi und Freunden gemacht.«_ _»Lebenspartner«_ finde ich auch zu förmlich, _»Darling«_ wäre wohl noch akzeptabel.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Mir ging es nur um die neue Zweideutigkeit, durch "Partner", was die Fragestellung wiederholen würde. Ansonsten kann ich es nachvollziehen.

Answer (score 0):

There is no common word in German such as "Freund" that encompasses both "friend" and boy/girl friend. Only the English language would conflate the two. They are basically two separate thoughts in German.

Terms such as Verliebter, Partner, or my favorite, Schatz, refers to someone of the opposite sex in a "serious," (marriage bound) relationship. For more casual relationships, "Freund" is appropriate. That is they are a friend but not a "special" friend.

A German uses "boy- girl-" friend terminology, as above, at a much later stage of a relationship than say, an American would. As such, there is also a greater separation from "friend." The English term "friend with benefits," refers to a sexual relationship with someone other than a future marriage partner. A German would use the term "Freund" to describe such a person.